# Could someone please explain error here in file handling

Tags: file-handling

I am writing a program which would store the student record in file named 'new' on desktop.
If there is no file named 'new' then it should create it first, so I have used an if statement. I have also put the whole code in a do while loop, so it should loop though the code again and again. Inside the do while I have used switch

1. to write to file using `fprintf`
2. code still not written( will add read function to it later on)
3. To exit out of do while loop

but I am getting an error `'ch' undeclared (first use this fucntion)`

How can I fix this program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct
{
int *name;
int score;
}structure;

int main()
{
FILE *file= fopen("C://Users//Abhimanyu Aryan//Desktop//new.txt","r");
if(file==NULL)
{
FILE *file=fopen("C://Users//Abhimanyu Aryan//Desktop//new.txt","w");
}

//Loop through this
do
{
printf("\n1) Add record\n2) View Record\n3) Exit");

int ch;
printf("Enter your choice: ");
scanf("%i",&ch);

switch (ch)
{
    //case 1 will include write access to file on pressing 1
case 1:
    //name
    printf("Enter name: ");
    char name[30];
    scanf("%c", name);
    //score
    printf("Enter score: ");
    int score;
    scanf("%i", &score);
    //printing to file
    fprintf(file, "%c\t%i", name, score);
    break;

//case still not in use
case 2:
    break;

//case to exit
case 3:
    break;

}
}while(ch != 3);

fclose(file);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you give us a complete copy of the error message/stacktrace?
Not just the message but the line of code that it was failing?

Comment: wait a sec uploading screenshots

Comment: no - screenshots are not as good - they're hard to read and you can't copy/paste from them. Just copy-paste the code in pleeeeese :)

Comment: E:\C Practice codes\filehandlingsir.c||In function 'main':|
E:\C Practice codes\filehandlingsir.c|55|error: 'ch' undeclared (first use in this function)|
E:\C Practice codes\filehandlingsir.c|55|note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Comment: bleh - comment formatting is yuck. Try editing your question and putting it at the bottom :)

Comment: so - even from what's in this comment - you can see that it's complaining about line 55 right?
so what line of code is line 55?

Comment: This question is a mess, the code doesn't even give the error in the title and it has multiple edits. What is going on?

Comment: I've rolled back several edits, going back to the original version of the question. The second version *fixed the problem*, thereby invalidating the answers. Some of the edits did fix grammar and code formatting, but I'm not going to try to unravel all that. The original poster doesn't even have an account anymore, so this is probably not going to be a terribly useful question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ah... the problem may well be this line of code:

```
} while (ch != 3)
```

the `ch` variable is defined *ONLY* inside the do-while loop...
I'd try to define it outside the loop and see if that helped

Comment: seems that we get the answer almost at the same time ;)

Comment: yaa got it done can you tell me one more thing how can i use clear screen `clrscr();` inside of a do while loop so i won't print same thing again and again everytime i loop through?

Comment: @Taryn East please have a look at code again...now the error is fix but when i try to store my input to the file using fprintf it doesn't write to the file... file is still empty

Comment: That is a second problem yes? Second question!

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize **ch** outside of do..while loop, that's the error

Comment: please have a look at code again...now the error is fix but when i try to store my input to the file using fprintf it doesn't write to the file... file is still empty

Comment: their is a logic error in file open, if the file exist, it will be open in read mode, so file write will not success. Beside, you can add  printf("%s\t%i", name, score) next to fprintf for debug purpose

Comment: can you suggest me an edit code for it? what should i edit and where? it's still not clear :(

Comment: still not working after i removed 
if(file==NULL)
FILE *file=fopen("C://Users//Abhimanyu Aryan//Desktop//new.txt","r");

now i am only using write command

Comment: how do you terminate the application? by using "ctrl+c"? if so the f.close is not called, the write content is still in memory, and not flushed to disk